# Printing variable and text with input command?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking for the syntax I would use to print both text and a saved int in the input function. I'm making a program that asks the user math questions using dynamic terms, and I want to be able to print those and some text on the same line.

I've tried this code, hoping that the parameters would be represented like it were a print statement:

```
answer = int(input(oneTerm, '+', twoTerm, '='))
```

I also tried using two lines like this:

```
print(oneTerm, '+', twoTerm, '=')
answer = int(input(''))
```

But the problem with this is the input is accepted on the line below the print statement, but I need it to be on the same line.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The `input()` function takes only *one* string argument (and not multiple, like `print()`). Use string formatting:

```
answer = int(input('{} + {} = '.format(oneTerm, twoTerm)))
```

The `{}` placeholders are replaced by the two arguments to `.format()`, creating essentially the same string to prompt the user for input.

See the [`str.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) documentation for more details.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question but I guess the best solution would be using F-strings for an updated aproach. This was released in Python >=3.6 in December 2016 (see **PEP 498**).

In a single line it would be:

```
answer = int(input(F'{oneTerm} + {twoTerm} ='))
```

I guess this is the more updated  way to do it and also the most readable. What you guys think about readability with F-strings? It's very nice, right?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of these methods simply try using:

```
answer = input(oneTerm, '+', twoTerm, '=')
answer = int(answer)
```

Comment: input expected at most 1 argument